# Is Sending a Request as a Page Possible?

Tags: facebook, request

Basically what the title asks.  I have an app that will send user (moderator) generated requests using the Javascript SDK's "apprequest" method, but instead of showing up in people's notifications drop down as coming from me, is it possible to show up as coming from a Page representing our business?  Considering how you can post as a Page, I would assume that this would be possible but I can't find any documentation on it anywhere.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657737/problem-with-posting-to-facebook-page-using-php-script-as-page-account

Comment: It's a possibility if there's no other option, but the problem is that PHP requests only increment the bookmark counter but don't actually trigger a notification.  Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score 0):

As Facebook explains in their documentation about the [Requests dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/),

> The Request Dialog sends a request from one user (the sender) to one or more other users (the recipients). These requests are used to elicit a social action between users, for example "Please join my Team" in a baseball game.

Since a [Facebook Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) is not the same as a [Facebook User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) (while they do have feeds, Pages do not have the [`apprequests` connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests)), authenticating to your application as a Page and trying to use the Requests dialog will not work. Even if it did, because the Requests dialog is JavaScript-based, you would need to **manually** login to process these requests.

An alternative solution is to use what Facebook calls an "App-Generated Request" by POSTing to a user's `apprequests` endpoint (I think this might be what you are referred to in your comment as a "PHP request"). Note that you would need to use an application access token (and not a Page access token).

Facebook has created a document summarizing [ways that Facebook Applications and Pages can communicate with their users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Communicating_With_Users/).